# how to install haste-compiler using cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal, haste

I'm trying to install haste-compiler using cabal..the instalation was ok, but when I run the command "haste boot" I face an error:[image]

Anyone knows how to fix this error? Thanks.

Comment: it's hard to tell if this is some silly windows thing (if in doubt try linux - if you want on a VM in Windows) or if the project is broken - btw: I think there are things missing from your picture - and this very picture is probably the reason for the downvote because simply copy&pasting the text from the command window would circumvent much not have this problem

Comment: from the picture is missing the user name, which isn't relevant..so I don't understand the part with the downvote..and about this error..I face it on every project I made it..I don't know why

Comment: I did not downvote so I can only guess - anyway there is an issues about this on [github](https://github.com/valderman/haste-compiler/issues/375) - maybe the proposed solutions there (use the binaries) work for you as well - as I said windows and many haskell related stuff don't work that well - grab yourself a VM ;)

Comment: ok..thanks for your suggestion..i'll try on linux